# SQL Azure Federation Database Backup

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, federation, sql-azure-federations

We are using SQL Azure Federation and now we want to take backup.

We tried using Migration tool and Enzo cloud backup utility but the SQL Federation version is deprecated in both of the tools.

Is there any alternative method to take backup of federated database apart from the one we have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can backup a Federation member database in the Azure portal by selecting the database and clicking on the "Export" button on the bottom of the screen.  This will create a backup of the database in a blob storage account.  The database can be restored as a regular SQL Database, but cannot be restored as a Federation member.

If you have not already seen the documentation, I highly suggest you take a look at the Federations Migrations document  [[link]](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-federation-migration/) the Federation Migration Utility [[link]](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Federations-Migration-ce61e9c1?clcid=0x409), and Elastic Scale [[link]](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-documentation-map/).